# Unable to detect http headers

Tags: angular, apache, ionic-framework

I've setup my api into web server, currently im unable to retrieve data using my app key but able to do so using postman, please do help

```
const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'APP_KEY': 'ABCDEFGHJ'

      })
    };

    this.http.get('<my_api_link>', httpOptions).subscribe((res) => {
      this.Result = JSON.stringify(res);
      console.log('Result', this.DataResult);
    }, (err) => {
      console.error(err.status);
      console.error(err.error); // Error message as string
      console.error(err.headers);
    });
```

Error message was unable to find app key

Answer (score 1):

Try to set headers this way

```
const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
  .set('APP_KEY', 'ABCDEFGHJ');

this.http.get('<my_api_link>', httpHeaders)
```

Comment: shouldn't headers be part of options object?

Comment: @KiraAG this way is also valid

Comment: actually all these 3 method provided is the same, just abit different on the structure, but still unable to detect the app key

Comment: How are you checking that key is not getting detected?

Comment: i output the entered key at console 
DataResult {"0":401,"message":"App key not found, entered API_KEY = "}

Comment: try to console and check at the intercepter level before API call.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var token = 'ABCDEFGHJ';
const myHeaders = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': token });
this.http.get('<my_api_link>', { headers: myHeaders });
```

Or

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.set('APP_KEY','ABCDEFGHJ');
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifying your code snippet :

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders().set('APP_KEY', 'ABCDEFGHJ')
};

this.http.get('<my_api_link>', httpOptions).subscribe((res) => {
  this.Result = JSON.stringify(res);
  console.log('Result', this.DataResult);
}, (err) => {
  console.error(err.status);
  console.error(err.error); // Error message as string
  console.error(err.headers);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient) {

// some code

}

Comment: https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-http-get-parameters-headers-urlsearchparams-requestoptions-example